# Como fazer union de duas queries usando Django Filter

Tags: python, banco-de-dados, django, orm

Estava quebrando a cabeça para fazer `union` de duas *queries* usando Django Filter e acabei fazendo na mão mesmo (`Model.objects.raw("SELECT....")`).

Como poderia fazer `union` com a ORM do Django?

Obs.: Tenho 2 tabelas diferentes com alguns campos em comum.

**Table1**

- table1_id
- name
- description
- created_at
- user_id

**Table2**

- table2_id
- name
- description
- created_at
- user_id

A relação que quero manter é entre o `user_id`. Quero unir esses registros e ordenar pelo `created_at`.

Comment: Só pra esclarecer, `UNION` você quer dizer literalmente juntar os resultados de uma query com a outra?

Comment: Sim, tenho 2 tabelas diferentes com alguns campos em comum. Vou editar no tópico.

Comment: Acho que você teria que fazer um for, tipo: `for obj in Table1.objects.all(): result += Table2.objects.filter(user_id=obj.user_id)`. Funciona?

Comment: Entre usar 2 selects e um `.raw` acho que é preferível o `.raw` né?

Comment: Em termos de performance, *acredito* que sim. Vale a pena fazer o teste. Acho que vai depender do tamanho da sua tabela também.

Answer (score 1):

Depende do tipo de relação que você procura, isto pode te ajudar:

```
Table1.objects.filter(user_id__in=[x.user_id for x in Table2.objects.all()]).order_by('created_at')
```

De qualquer forma, você consegue testar o equivalente em SQL de qualquer query em Django da seguinte forma:

```
query_aleatoria = Table1.objects.filter(description__contains='abacaxi')
print(query_aleatoria.query) # considerando python 3+
```

*Edit*:

Sugiro que revise sua estrutura de Banco de Dados, esse `user_id` me parece um bom candidato a chave estrangeira, em cujo caso, a query ficaria mais fácil. Se puder incluir na sua pergunta o seu modelo relacional, seria de grande ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

```
qs1 = Table1.objects.values("user_id", "created_at")
qs2 = Table2.objects.values("user_id", "created_at")
qs1.union(qs2).order_by("created_at")
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#union

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra forma que encontrei de fazer funcionar é usando o `chain`.

```
from itertools import chain

query1 = Blog1.objects.all()
query2 = Blog2.objects.all()

posts = list( chain(query1, query2) )
```